# Como zerar ProgressBar sem utizar efeito?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Estou realizando várias importações, e quando realizo o *upload* de um novo arquivo preciso zerar o progresso, isto eu consigo setando o `width` com *0px*, porém ele zera com um efeito no qual eu não gostaria de utilizar.

### Exemplo:

```js
var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");

var acionaProgresso = setInterval(addProgress, 1000);

function addProgress() {
  var width = progressBar.width() + 40;
  progressBar.width(width);
}

$("#zeraProgressBar").click(function() {
  progressBar.width('0%');
  clearInterval(acionaProgresso);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <h4 class="text-center">Importando arquivos</h4>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="40" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
    <br>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="zeraProgressBar">
      Zerar Progress Bar
    </button>
  </div>

</div>
```

Como posso limpar o progresso sem utilizar este efeito ?

Comment: É "gambiarra", mas eu acho que o único jeito é colocar um id na sua progress bar, selecionar ele pelo jquery, desabilitar a animação colocando none, e depois dar removeattr na propriedade da animação, pra ele voltar a usar o que vem da role de progressbar do bootstrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto acontece por causa do efeito `transition` do *css*, se você remover ele irá remover o progresso de uma só vez!

Adicione ao seu zeraProgressBar:

```
progressBar.css('-webkit-transition', 'none').css('transition', 'none');
```

Exemplo funcionando no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jne2wfe1/)